# How to convert string year-month to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

DATE

```
202205
202204
202112
202202
202203
202201
```

I have a date column entered numerically. I have returned this column to object but I don't know how to make it datetime. I get an error because there is no Year-Month-Day on the roads I tried. Any suggestions?

Comment: datetime.strptime()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment Python datetime module has a strptime() method which parses string to datetime objects.
here is an example for your use case

```
from datetime import datetime
time_str = "202205"
format_str = "%Y%m"
parsed_date = datetime.strptime(time_str, format_str)
print(parsed_date)
```

this outputs

```
2022-05-01 00:00:00
```

please note that if your date string does have any day or time fields then the resultant object will be having the default values.

To learn more about datetime module and strptime method in specific refer to this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-strptime-function/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question with this answer

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()
```